# Is it possible to control the originating phone number when using email to SMS gateways?

Tags: email, sms

I have a script that sends SMS alerts using email to SMS gateways like xxxxxxxxxx@txt.att.net. The number that the text appears to originate from is different every time, which prevents me from setting a custom text tone for the alerts, and also keeps the iPhone from grouping the alerts.

Anyone know of a way to control the originating phone number (or free services that will enable you to do so)?

Comment: Some operators allow you to do this - for a fee. I'm not familiar with AT&T specifically, but go ahead and ask their sales dept. (Oh, you meant for free? No can do, I'm afraid - that's exactly the point of free/paid/premium service grades: offer finer control for more money)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up making this work by hacking Google Voice:

http://rc3.org/2011/08/07/how-i-got-automated-texts-to-originate-from-one-number/

Not the most robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes but it can be costly! You can get your own Short Code from an aggregator like

- http://www.openmarket.com (short code)
- http://www.twilio.com/api/sms (messaging service/short code)
- http://www.clickatell.com/developers/clickatell_api.php?cid=179819 (shared short code filtered with keywords)

but using the Email SMS Gateway it's a crap shoot and 99% one way communication